# emmeans for betareg is giving me identical arrow ranges when plotting comparisions = T

Tags: lsmeans, beta-regression

My response is a ratio (length of a discoloration disease in the plant divided by the height of the plant), so is always (0, 1). Actually, sometimes it could be [0, 1), i.e., including zeros.
As I have some zeros, I transformed them accordingly with `betareg` [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/vignettes/betareg.pdf):

> a useful transformation in practice is (y · (n − 1) + 0.5)/n where n is the sample size (Smithson and Verkuilen 2006).

By the way, this is the (transformed) response distribution:

```r
summary(data_nonna$tpercent_discoloration)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
0.0003636 0.0380720 0.1726520 0.2158268 0.3462657 0.9408556
```

My beta regression model is as follows:

```r
library(betareg)
library(emmeans)

b1 <- betareg(
  tpercent_discoloration ~ cv + zone_line + severity,
  link = 'logit',
  data = data_nonna
)
```

where `cv` is a factor of different cultivars (18 levels), `zone_line` is a factor of 0 or 1, and `severity` is another factor with levels 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5, so all my predictors are factors.

As one of my objectives is to compare the cultivar levels, i.e. which one has the lower percentage of discoloration, of which one has the larger percentage of discoloration etc, and check whether they differ, I started to use `emmeans`.
Firstly I plotted the comparisons and saw that all the arrows were identical (same low and upper values for every `cv`), so I changed it to `plotit = F` to take a look at the data being plotted.

Here are the results:

```r
emm_betareg <- emmeans(b1, specs = 'cv', type = 'response')
comps <- plot(emm_betareg, CIs = F, comparisons = T, plotit = F)
comps
cv               the.emmean         SE  df  asymp.LCL asymp.UCL pri.fac              lcmpl     rcmpl
 CPLRC5007         0.1584522 0.02699608 Inf 0.10554081 0.2113635 CPLRC5007        0.1051907 0.2190178
 CPLRC5663         0.1485528 0.02561763 Inf 0.09834319 0.1987625 CPLRC5663        0.1051907 0.2190178
 DK4866            0.1864413 0.02767189 Inf 0.13220539 0.2406772 DK4866           0.1051907 0.2190178
 DT97-4290         0.1613726 0.02739499 Inf 0.10767936 0.2150657 DT97-4290        0.1051907 0.2190178
 Exp1_Stine39LA02  0.1157786 0.02077353 Inf 0.07506324 0.1564940 Exp1_Stine39LA02 0.1051907 0.2190178
 Exp2_XC3810       0.1503152 0.02642073 Inf 0.09853150 0.2020988 Exp2_XC3810      0.1051907 0.2190178
 Jack              0.1073797 0.02001452 Inf 0.06815195 0.1466074 Jack                    NA 0.2190178
 JTN-4307          0.1835275 0.03059703 Inf 0.12355838 0.2434965 JTN-4307         0.1051907 0.2190178
 JTN-5208          0.1099293 0.02082648 Inf 0.06911017 0.1507485 JTN-5208         0.1051907 0.2190178
 JTN-5308          0.1290918 0.02378328 Inf 0.08247745 0.1757062 JTN-5308         0.1051907 0.2190178
 K07-1544          0.1690793 0.02827543 Inf 0.11366044 0.2244981 K07-1544         0.1051907 0.2190178
 LS980358          0.1231427 0.02113839 Inf 0.08171223 0.1645732 LS980358         0.1051907 0.2190178
 MorsoyRT5388N     0.1901965 0.03489674 Inf 0.12180018 0.2585929 MorsoyRT5388N    0.1051907 0.2190178
 NKBrandS39-A3     0.1328391 0.02656402 Inf 0.08077458 0.1849036 NKBrandS39-A3    0.1051907 0.2190178
 Osage             0.1519922 0.02967803 Inf 0.09382435 0.2101601 Osage            0.1051907 0.2190178
 Pharaoh           0.2168288 0.04980157 Inf 0.11921949 0.3144381 Pharaoh          0.1051907        NA
 R01581F           0.1949003 0.03568743 Inf 0.12495428 0.2648464 R01581F          0.1051907 0.2190178
 Spencer           0.1163156 0.02318274 Inf 0.07087824 0.1617529 Spencer          0.1051907 0.2190178

Results are averaged over the levels of: zone_line, severity 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

As you can see, both `lcmpl` and `rcmpl` are the same for each `cv` level.
We also have two NAs, which, as I understood, it's because we don't need to compare the lower level to the left and the higher value to the right.

Also, the results say:

> Results are averaged over the levels of: zone_line, severity

so I thought to check the contingency table for the predictors:

```r
table(data_nonna$cv, data_nonna$zone_line)
                  
                    0  1
  CPLRC5007        48 22
  CPLRC5663        72  8
  DK4866           67 13
  DT97-4290        75  5
  Exp1_Stine39LA02 67 13
  Exp2_XC3810      78  2
  Jack             79  1
  JTN-4307         61  8
  JTN-5208         79  1
  JTN-5308         78  1
  K07-1544         80  0
  LS980358         69 10
  MorsoyRT5388N    78  2
  NKBrandS39-A3    74  5
  Osage            74  5
  Pharaoh          38  2
  R01581F          79  1
  Spencer          72  8
```

```r
table(data_nonna$cv, data_nonna$severity)
                  
                    1  2  3  4  5
  CPLRC5007         2  6 17 40  5
  CPLRC5663         3  6 23 41  7
  DK4866            2  5 26 34 13
  DT97-4290         0 10 29 36  5
  Exp1_Stine39LA02  4  5 28 40  3
  Exp2_XC3810       3  1 35 31 10
  Jack              0  3 14 47 16
  JTN-4307          2  9 14 37  7
  JTN-5208          3 15 27 30  5
  JTN-5308          4 10 24 37  4
  K07-1544          0  5 29 38  8
  LS980358          2  5 16 35 21
  MorsoyRT5388N     1  9 24 38  8
  NKBrandS39-A3     3  8 24 33 11
  Osage             1  6 23 39 10
  Pharaoh           1  5  5 18 11
  R01581F           5  8 12 28 27
  Spencer           2  4 18 45 11
```

We have different values, so I expected to have different "arrows" for each `cv`.
Sorry if I'm making some silly mistake, but I don't know what is going on.

Any idea of what could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The identical arrows is not at all surprising. That's because `emmeans()` summarises your *model*, not the data, and your model is additive. You have no interaction effects, which implies that the effects of one factor are the same regardless of the level of any other factors. If you expect different comparisons, you need to fit a model that has interactions.

#### Revised answer

The above is not a correct answer because I did not read the OP carefully enough and misinterpreted it.

The question is about why all the comparison arrows all have the same endpoints. This I think I can explain. First, the method and algorithm, which is a bit *ad hoc*, is explained in the ["xplanations" vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/xplanations.html#arrows). Briefly, we try to get each pair of comparison arrows to overlap by the same fraction as the (adjusted) confidence interval for the difference of those means overlaps the origin. But in this example, at least after multiplicity adjustments, no two means are anywhere near significantly different; that is, all the adjusted confidence intervals overlap the origin, so all the arrows should overlap.

But second, for practical display reasons, there is really no reason to extend a comparison arrow any farther left than the lowest mean, nor any farther right than the largest mean: If two arrows are going to overlap, they will have started overlapping somewhere between those extremes. So it appears that all of the arrows we computed *would* have extended out of this range, and so they all got truncated to values slightly beyond the min and the max.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to be able to say that one cultivar has less likelihood of being diseased to the other ones, for example. Or that one cultivar has more likelihood to the other ones, but I don't care with pairwise comparisions. Can I do this type of interpretation with the arrow comparisions (if they not overlap) or should I use a contrast with "eff" method?

Comment: Reviewing this again, I am not sure why the comparison arrows are all the same. But it might be to the multiplicity problem with adjusting P values for such a huge family of pairwise comparisons. I think you might well be better off doing `eff` or `del.eff` contrasts with a suitable P-value adjustment, perhaps `sidak`.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. I did contrast with "eff" and I'm not sure how to interpret the p-values. If for a `cv` the p-value is e.g. < 0.05, can I say that we do not reject the hypothesis that the (predicted) disease for this `cv` is statistically lower (or higher) than the other ones?

Comment: No. You can say it is statistically lower (or higher) than the *average* of all the other ones.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer! How can I obtain contrasts for the response scale rather than the logit? I'm getting results in `odds.ratio`, but I would like to report in the response scale (0, 1). My `emmeans` was in the response scale, but contrast is not.

Comment: Do `emm2 <- regrid(emm_betareg)` which converts everything to the response scale and forgets it was ever on the logit scale. Then `contrast(emm2)` will do the contrasts on the response scale rather than the odds ratio scale.

Comment: I did this but I got negative values and thought I was doing the wrong thing. I have negative values such as `-0.04914347`, `-0.06208520` etc. I'm not sure why this happened though. Do you know what could be happening?

Comment: Negative values of the *contrast estimates* would just indicate that the mean being subtracted is greater than the other one. If you're talking about negative confidence limits of the means, that can happen because with re-gridding, we are computing them on the response scale, rather than on the logit scale and back-transforming them. Maybe you'll think again about those odds ratios; those really are what you get with contrasts of log-odds (logits) when you put them on the response scale.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I'm done now.